# How to write a custom Transformer in MLlib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I want to write a custom `Transformer` for a pipeline in spark 2.0 in scala. So far it is not really clear for me what the `copy` or `transformSchema` methods should return. Is it correct that they return a `null`? https://github.com/SupunS/play-ground/blob/master/test.spark.client_2/src/main/java/CustomTransformer.java for copy?

As the `Transformer` extends `PipelineStage` I conclude, that a `fit` calls the `transformSchema` method. Do I understand correctly that `transformSchema` is similar to sk-learns fit?

As my `Transformer` should join the dataset with a (very small) second dataset I want to store that one in the serialized pipeline as well. How should I store this in the transformer to properly work with the pipelines serialization mechanism?

How would a simple transformer look like which computes the mean for a single column and fills the nan values + persists this value?

```
@SerialVersionUID(serialVersionUID) // TODO store ibanList in copy + persist
    class Preprocessor2(someValue: Dataset[SomeOtherValues]) extends Transformer {

      def transform(df: Dataset[MyClass]): DataFrame = {

      }

      override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = {
      }

      override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
        schema
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transformSchema` should return the schema which is expected after applying `Transformer`. Example:

- If transfomer adds column of `IntegerType`, and output column name is `foo`:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
     schema.add(StructField("foo", IntegerType))
  }
  ```

> So if the schema is not changed for the dataset as only a name value is filled for mean imputation I should return the original case class as the schema?

It is not possible in Spark SQL (and MLlib, too) since a `Dataset` is **immutable** once created. You can only add or "replace" (which is add followed by `drop` operations) columns.

Comment: you mean a transformer which drops / adds new columns should be an estimator? This sounds strange. So do I understand correct an sklearn transformer with fit & transform is a spark estimator, a spark transformer can only perform "fixed" transformations which are constant for any input data. As such a mean imputer needs to be an estimator?

Comment: As @LostInOverflow said, what you need an estimator and then a transformer -- where the estimator computes the mean from the original column and then the transformer imputes the missing values with the computed mean. Also, missing value imputation is a feature that is currently in the cooking -- [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13568)

Comment: Thanks. Ist it correct that any variable in the Estimator's fit which should be stored / persisted will actually be persisted?

Comment: Params should be. The rest, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm not sure you want a `Transformer` per se (or `UnaryTransformer` as [@LostInOverflow suggested in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615898/1305344)) as you said:

> How would a simple transformer look like which computes the mean for a single column and fills the nan values + persists this value?

For me, it's as if you wanted to apply a aggregate function (aka aggregation) and "join" it with all the columns to produce the final value or NaN.

It *looks* like you want a `groupBy` to do aggregation for `mean` and then `join` which could be a window aggregation, too.

Anyway, I'd start with a `UnaryTransformer` which would solve the first issue in your question:

> So far it is not really clear for me what the `copy` or `transformSchema` methods should return. Is it correct that they return a null?

See [the complete project spark-mllib-custom-transformer at GitHub](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-workshop/tree/gh-pages/solutions/spark-mllib-custom-transformer) in which I implemented the `UnaryTransformer` to `toUpperCase` a string column which for the UnaryTransformer looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.UnaryTransformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StringType}

class UpperTransformer(override val uid: String)
  extends UnaryTransformer[String, String, UpperTransformer] {

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("upp"))

  override protected def createTransformFunc: String => String = {
    _.toUpperCase
  }

  override protected def outputDataType: DataType = StringType
}
```